# Ampère's Law Confusion (Basic)

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

Ampère's Law in its integral form (ignoring the term Maxwell introduced for capacitors) essentially says that the total magnetic field directed around a closed loop is proportional to the current flowing in it. This carries the implication that any loop of creates a corresponding magnetic field (the basis of solenoids etc). Please do correct anything incorrect in the above!
My question is this: does the converse of the above work (i.e.: does a magnetic field create a current in a wire). My intuition says this is wrong since in most of EM you need some notion of a changing field for any effect to be produced.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're right throughout – including your intuition about requiring a $changing$ magnetic field (or motion of a conductor through a field). [Faraday didn't know this when he first started looking for an electrical effect of magnetic fields to partner the recently discovered magnetic effect of an electric current.]

Comment: *"total magnetic field directed around a closed loop is proportional to the current flowing in it."* - it's proportional to the current through the surface bounded by the loop.  Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in your description and intuition of Ampère's law - the presence of a magnetic field does not imply a current will be created in a nearby wire. However, there are two things to note:

1. The presence of the magnetic field implies there is a current *somewhere* (no current = no magnetic field).
2. If you start in a situation with a superconducting loop of wire and no magnetic field, and they you create a magnetic field (by sending current through a loop somewhere), then you will indeed get a corresponding current in the superconducting loop (so as to keep the flux through the loop unchanged). But as you say, at some point during the experiment this required a changing field (but after that, it can remain static and the current will continue).